# Let's clean up some OS tags

Tags: discussion, tag-clean-up

This is Web Apps. Web Apps, by and large, shouldn't care about what a user's underlying operating system is. Still, we have a bunch of questions that are tagged with operating system names.

- [linux](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux) x15
- [windows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) x20
- [windows-7](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) x7
- [osx](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx) x15

  - [mac](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac) x23 is technically hardware, but I think it applies here
- [ios](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) x9

  - [iphone](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) x36 is technically hardware, but I think it applies here
- [android](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) x29

Now *maybe* some of these are correctly applied. (I don't have an example of what such a use might be at the moment.) If so, then leave the tag.

In most cases, though, the tag was used to describe the Asker's system, not to describe what their question was actually about. In those cases the tag should be removed.

As always with any clean up project, *don't just fix this issue*. If you're going to edit, edit everything that's wrong with the post. Fix grammar/spelling, fix formatting, remove greetings, remove "thanks", remove signatures, etc. And limit yourself to just a few at a time so the front page doesn't get overloaded.

Of course, if the question should be closed, then vote/flag as appropriate. (Probably shouldn't bother editing.)

Comment: IMHO, at this time, all the [tag:android] questions in WA "deals with the overall system and not just the Android interface" (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/76552/new-gmail-contacts-in-android#comment64319_76552), but I consider that it's relevant to know the mobile device OS of the asker as the "overall system" usually has a limited set of features for the mobile app and are not the same to other mobile device OS.

Comment: @Rubén: That's why humans need to evaluate each case. It very well could be true that an issue is specific to Android and so the tag should stay. If that's true, though, maybe the question needs to be at [android.se]. Certainly any native apps (vs. web app interfaces in a browser on Android) are off-topic here.